# Remove "at" date format

Tags: swift

Looks like apple is defaulting the date with an `at`, how can I replace that `at` with a comma? Here's an example:

Expected result: `"Mon, Oct 10, 11:22 am"`

> Below withLocalizedLocale is using `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`

```
let formatter = DateFormatter(withLocalizedLocale: "E, MMM d, h:mma")
formatter.amSymbol = "am"
formatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
```

Here's the output of the above: `"Mon, Oct 10 at 11:22 am"`

I tried with a space and it's the same result, however other formats such as `"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mma"` works correctly, so I'm puzzle by what's going on

Comment: IMO you should accept the format generated based on the locale as it is. If you need a custom format you need to use a fixed date format. Btw you are not showing your custom init declaration. I suspect it uses a template not a dateFormat

Comment: I need that format. What do you mean fixed date format? @LeoDabus

Comment: When using a template the components order doesn't matter. It will be defined using the locale.

Comment: Yes, I'm using in this case a template, I'm setting it like `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(withLocalizedLocale)`. So since the components using the template doesn't apply in this case, I must use Dateformat? @LeoDabus

Comment: If you need a custom dateFormat yes. The template only defines which components will be used based on a Locale therefore all you need to pass for your template is `"EMMMdhmm"` but as you have already figure out you don't have control over the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` is from your locale `DateFormatter`. So for your problem, you just need to change locale identifier to `en_US` so device not formate date to your locale one.

```swift
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "E, MMM d, h:mm a"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.amSymbol = "am"
formatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
print("date: ", formatter.string(from: date))
```

Comment: So the magic is on `_POSIX`? If so, right now I'm assigning the locale identifier as is: `en_US`, depending on the country. Would there be any implications to other locales in assigning that postfix?

Comment: Also changing the timezone changes the date itself :/

Comment: Dear @Arturo, I make mistake that I didn't read your question carefully. Just update my answer. You just need to define ``locale`` to default which is ``en_US`` instead of using your default localize locale.

Comment: After iOS 10+, Apple switch to ``ISO 8601`` for ``DateFormatter`` so don't need to use ``_POSIX``

Comment: That seems to work as expected, but I'm getting the am/pm close to the date, how can I add a space there to match the format? This is how it looks: `Mon, Oct 10, 11:22am`, this is how it should be `Mon, Oct 10, 11:22 am`

Comment: Dear @Arturo, ``formatter.dateFormat = "E, MMM d, h:mm a"`` just need to add space.

Comment: lol yep I added it and tested after asking. Thank you for the help!